# panel with scrollbar in c#

Tags: c#, scrollbar, panel

i am trying to create a POS system, and there will be buttons creating dynamically,  wondering what is the best way to create or layout the buttons.

I am currently using Metro Framework for C# window form, is there a way to create a pannel to have fixed amount of rows, and x columns of buttons so that if it has more than x columns, it will generate a scroll bar for you to slide to the rest of the buttons.

thank you

Comment: If you are going with the `Row` and `Column` approach it would be better to use `DataGridView`. or else you can try something like a `Panel(*with fixed width*) = [button(*with fixed width*)+Offset]` and then make a calculation of how many buttons can be added in a line.

Comment: Use a FlowLayout Pannel